# Can I deploy a Spring WebFlux application as a WAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, war, spring-webflux

Here

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

I read that "War deployment is not supported for WebFlux applications". Is it only restricted for spring-boot applications or I cant do it at all with spring web flux? Assuming I don't user boot configurations and starters.

Answer (score 1):

You' referring to the Spring Boot documentation here - this limitation only applies to Spring Boot.

You can deploy a Spring WebFlux application (outside of Spring Boot) as a WAR file inside a Servlet 3.1+ container. For that, [the Spring Framework reference documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler):

> To deploy as a WAR to any Servlet 3.1+ container, you can extend and
>   include AbstractReactiveWebInitializer in the WAR. That class wraps an
>   HttpHandler with ServletHttpHandlerAdapter and registers that as a
>   Servlet.

Comment: What is the workaround for Spring boot webflux application to be deployed as WAR in tomcat?